# Running python script from Excel corrupts my .xslm file but not when running script from VSC

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlsxwriter, xlwings

After a lot of trial and error I found a way to extract data in a dataframe from a .xlsm file without corrupting the file extension. It had to do with removing the vbaProject.bin using workbook.add_vba_project.
Now I am running into an issue where I run my python script from an excel macro using the RunPythonScript action. When I run my python script from there, it corrupts the .xlsm file and I can no longer open it. But when I run my python script from Visual Studio Code again, it uncorrupts the file?

```
df_1 = pd.concat([df_1,df])
print(df_1) 
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/Users/path/Test_17.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df_1.to_excel(writer, index=False)
workbook = writer.book
workbook.filename = 'C:/Users/path/Test_17.xlsm'
workbook.add_vba_project('vbaProject.bin')
writer.save()
```

Comment: Try providing the full path to `vbaProject.bin`